# Selection.style applied to wrong paragraph (and other issues)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have multiple documents coming from the same template. Each of them starts with a chapter number, so that I can build a table of contents that includes all of them. Since chapters have sections and subsections, I created a multilevel list style called MyList. Since they are different documents and all lists would start at 1, I need to specify the chapter number manually.

This can be achieved by writing {LISTNUM MyList \l 1 \s x} on the first line, x being chapter number. I wrote a macro to prompt for the chapter number, insert a carriage return and apply a new paragraph style to type the chapter name:

> **Chapter 1** (style: ChapNum)
>
> *Chapter name here* (style: ChapName)
>
> Normal text blah blah

The (working) code I have right now is:

```
Sub ChapterNumber()

Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("ChapNum")
ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = True
Num = InputBox("Chapter number", "Random title")
SendKeys "^{F9}"
Selection.InsertBefore Text:="LISTNUM MyList \l 1 \s " + Num
SendKeys "%{F9}{RIGHT}{ENTER}"
End Sub
```

I have encountered a few issues until I finally got there, which are:

I was unable to apply a different paragraph style after the last Sendkeys using `Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("ChapName")` since the whole thing converted to ChapName style, not only the paragraph where the cursor was pointing.

I've read Sendkeys is not that reliable so, initially, instead of `SendKeys "%{F9}{RIGHT}{ENTER}"`, I tried

```
ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = False
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
Sendkeys "{ENTER}"
```

Neither of the first two commands worked, and I don't know why; I have used them in other macros and never had any problem. Would you please be so kind to clarify? Please take in mind my knowledge of vba is very limited.

Thank you.

Comment: If you are using a template why are you using VBA to set paragraph styles? Just add the paragraphs to the template in the required styles and the styling will already be done. Then you just need to add the LISTNUM field and some text.

Comment: I agree completely with Timothy Rylatt's comment and answer, short term. Long term, you need to learn more about how templates work and how to set numbering attached to styles. Here is my page on templates: http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm Here is the best page on using automatic numbering: http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html

Comment: Charles, it is true that I need to learn much more about templates; it's the first time I've had the need of one, so there are still many things I don't know. My styles are already linked to my list, and the first level already has the word "Chapter" included in it; my main problem is that I need to override automatic numbering because every chapter is in a separate document, so all of them would be "Chapter 1".

Comment: Timothy, you might be right there; the thing is, I never used templates before, so I'm quite new to this. VBA was simply to override chapter numbers easily using a window prompt, and I guessed I could also insert some other commands for styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the text "Chapter " to your template and apply the correct style. Add empty paragraphs in the other two required styles and your template is already setup for you to start typing. All that is then required is to add the LISTNUM field which can be done as shown below.

```
Sub ChapterNumber()
    Dim Num As Long
    Num = InputBox("Chapter number", "Random title")
    Dim location As Range
    With ActiveDocument
        Set location = .Paragraphs(1).Range.Characters.Last
        location.Move wdCharacter, -1
        .Fields.Add Range:=location, Text:="LISTNUM MyList \l 1 \s " & Num
    End With
End Sub
```

EDIT IN RESPONSE TO COMMENTS:

As you appear to have defined numbered styles in your template you do need to add  the LISTNUM field. Instead you should set the start at number for the list template attached to the style.

```
Sub ChapterNumber()
    Dim Num As Long
    Num = InputBox("Chapter number", "Random title")
    ActiveDocument.Styles("ChapNum").ListTemplate.ListLevels(2).StartAt = Num
End Sub
```

Comment: I actually read about adding fields a few days ago but, for some reason, totally forgot about that command in particular when I actually needed it. I will try your suggestion as soon as I'm able to. Thanks!

Comment: I tried your code and it works flawlessly, thanks! If I understand things correctly, "location" is the end of the first paragraph, right? And you apply the field there (Range:= location). Does location.Move modify the initial definition of Location? If not, what does it do?

Comment: Update to the previous comment: The style defined in MyList doesn't automatically get applied to the first paragraph. I checked the list and the first level is correctly linked to the style. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Clairekun - yes `location` initially points to the last character in the paragraph, which is the end of paragraph marker. `location.Move wdCharacter, -1` shifts the range back by one character.

Comment: @Clairekun - If you haven't already done so you may find it helpful to review Shauna Kelly's article on [numbered styles](https://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html) Although written for WD2010 it is still valid and remains the best explanation available.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. The only problem I am facing now is that, since the chapter name is in a different line, Chapter Number label disappears as soon as I enter a carriage return because there is nothing after the number, but that discussion doesn't belong here. Thanks again :).

Comment: @Clairekun - yes I should have pointed out that will happen. There are two solutions to that, 1) if the next para is in the same style you can follow the number with a line break (Shift + Enter); 2) if the next para is in a different style just add a space. You can set that up in your template.

Comment: I did know about the space trick, but thanks for poiting it out in case I forget or anyone else needs it.